# Send Origin header while loading js scripts

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers

I'm storing my static files on different domain and I want my remote static server returns files with CORS headers, but my server should get "Origin" header in request to allow CORS headers. Unfortunately  Chrome and FF doesn't send this header when I try load my js script with usual
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my-another-static-server.com/js/script.js"></script>`

When I see in Chrome's network panel I see only these request headers for this request:

`Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:my-another-static-server.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:63342/example.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36`

I know that browsers add Origin header for cross-domain request if we use XMLHttpRequest, but here we send request with native browsers technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is tag `crossorigin=anonymous` that solved this problem. Now when I load script my browser also send Origin header.